# Is it safe to assign a _bstr_t com property a LPCTSTR?

Tags: c++, string, com

I come across some code where a LPCTSTR is assigend to a _bstr_t. As a BSTR does provide length information according to MSDN and a common TCHAR pointer does not I am unsure if the following code is safe. I did not find a clue that there is an overloaded operator that makes this possible safely, however this seems to work without any obvious errors, but it might be undefined behaviour.

Example:

```
// pComObject->Property is of type _bstr_t
pComObject->Property = (LPCTSTR) string;
```

Comment: I'm curious about the `LPCTSTR` cast... what is the type of `string`? If string is an instance of `std::string` or `std::wstring`, you should use `c_str()` method. If `string` is an instance of `CString`, there is an implicit `LPCTSTR` conversion operator.

Comment: string is a `CString`, so the right part is ok. I missed to look at the assignment operators though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `_bstr_t` has an [operator=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bh2f8sk.aspx) which accepts a NULL-terminated string (both wide and multibyte), so this is safe